# マージの取り消しをしたい（プッシュしていない状態）リモート有り

Tags: git

マージの取り消しをしたいです教えて下さい。

間違ってマージをしてしまいました。
現在のブランチがHEADでマージをしたら、masterブランチが消えてしまいました。
プッシュはしていない状態なので、リモートの方は何も更新されてない状態だと思っています。

どのような操作を行えば良いでしょうか？SourceTreeを使っております。

こちらの参考にしようかと思っていますが正しいでしょうか？
[参考URL](http://blog.livedoor.jp/noanoa07/archives/1981451.html)

> 『※マージのコミットを打ち消す操作は SourceTree
>   ではできないようです。右上の「端末」ボタンを押すと、ターミナルが開くのでコマンドを入力します。 「git revert -m1
>   HEAD」（直前のコミットの場合）。直前のコミットでない場合は、HEAD ではなくそのコミットのハッシュ値にします。』

追記8/11
masterブランチは消えていないと言うことですね。
こちらを参考にすれば、ソースツリーのグラフを元の状態に戻せますか？

[参考２](http://qiita.com/muran001/items/dea2bbbaea1260098051)

> やらかし１５：マージしたけどやっぱり元に戻したい時
>
> あくまで他者に取り込まれていない場合です！
>    マージする。 
>   $ git checkout <マージ先ブランチ>
>    $ git merge <マージ元ブランチ>
>
> マージしたあと、やっぱやめよって思ったらこれをやる
>    ORIG_HEADを指定すればマージ前に戻る
>      $ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD

Comment: gitにおける`HEAD`はブランチではなく、特定のコミットへの参照です。また、`detached HEAD`の状態でマージをしても`master`ブランチが消えることはありません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「元に戻す」というのが良く分からないのですが、コミットの参照を`master`やその他ブランチから外すことを、`detached HEAD`といい、この状態で行った変更はどこかのブランチを再度`checkout`すればなかったことになります。

ですので、GUI上から`master`ブランチを再度チェックアウトしてみてはどうでしょうか。

gitを覚えたばかりのときは、今何をして、どういう状態になっているのか、訳が分からなくなるかもしれません。そこで、`git reflog`コマンドを覚えることをお奨めします。これはローカルのブランチに行った変更の履歴を見ることができます。特定の状態に`checkout`できるので、おおよそどうにでもなります。